Fundamental lemma of variational calculus: extension to distributions
I am interested in the extension of the fundamental lemma of variational calculus to the world of distributions. The expected result would be something like:
$$\langle T,\phi\rangle=0,\quad \forall T\in \mathcal{D}'\quad\implies\quad \phi =0 \in\mathcal{D}$$
Does such a result exist? If yes, I am interested in a reference. It might  be obvious though.
Edits A better version would be:
$$\langle T,\phi\rangle=0,\quad \forall T\in \mathcal{D}', \quad \text{$T$ singular}\quad\implies\quad \phi =0 \in\mathcal{D}$$

Yes it is very obvious. GIven $\psi\in\mathcal{D}(U)$, let $T_{\psi}$ be the distribution defined by integration: $\phi\mapsto \int_{U}\psi\phi\,dx$.
Now, suppose $\phi\in \mathcal{D}(U)$ is such that for all $T\in \mathcal{D}’(U)$, $\langle T,\phi\rangle=0$. Then, in particular for all $\psi\in \mathcal{D}(U)$, we have $\langle T_{\psi},\phi\rangle =0$, i.e $\phi$ is such that for all $\psi$, $\int_U\phi\psi\,dx=0$. So, by one of the usual variants of the fundamental lemma of the calculus of variations, we get $\phi=0$.
If you don’t know this version, then repeat the argument with $T_f$, where $f\in L^1_{\text{loc}}(U)$ or $C_c(U)$ or any of the familiar collections of functions for which you already know a fundamental lemma of calculus of variations.
The reason why this should immediately be obvious to you is that you’re making the very strong assumption that pairing $\phi$ against all distributions gives $0$ (and there are many distributions). The question becomes more interesting once you restrict the class of distributions/functions against which the pairing of $\phi$ vanishes.

Edit.
An even shorter proof is to say that for all $x\in U$, we have $0=\langle \delta_x,\phi\rangle=\phi(x)$, and so $\phi=0$.

yes, sorry, it is very obvious this way, using the argument with regular distributions. As you noted, my question targets singular distributions. Edits made.

@pluton that’s still very easy as in my edit. You need to consider “small” collections of distributions; that’s when the question is interesting.

yes, sure, thanks! I'll leave my question as it is for now. I find it a bit strange that the fundamental lemma of variational calculus is never (??) expressed in this distributional sense though.

If we use your last argument with $\delta_x'$ (distributional derivative of $\delta_x$), we get for all $x\in U$, $\langle\delta_x',\phi\rangle=-\langle\delta_x,\phi'\rangle=0$ implies $\phi'(x)=0$ implies $\phi$ is the constant function on $U$. In other words, there are small collections of distributions for which the statement is not true.

But compact support of $\phi$ implies the locally constant values must all be $0$. Similar arguments if you restrict yourself to higher derivatives of $\delta$.

ah yes, this is true.

For fixed $\phi$ one can also take $T=T_\phi$ giving $\int \phi^2 = 0,$ i.e. $\phi=0.$

@md2perpe perfect (or if dealing with complex-valued functions, $T_{\overline{\phi}}$).
